# Como salvar PDF em banco e ter opção para o usuário baixar?

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, django, reportlab

Olá, estou com o seguinte problema:

Em um site o usuário entra com login e senha, ja está feito essa parte. Eu preciso guardar PDF's em um banco de dados ou então salva-los em um diretório e usar o banco de dados apenas com o caminho deles. Nessa aplicação o usuario, quando logado, teria como baixar o seu certificado, sem ter acesso a certificados de outros usuários, claro.
Eu gostaria de usar python para isso.
Não tenho experiência em projetos assim, seria meu primeiro. Eu tenho apenas essa noção do que fazer, mas não sei como implementar ou que ferramentas posso utilizar. Poderiam me ajudar nisso e dar dicas de material de estudo, vídeos, documentação e etc pra eu fazer essa aplicação web?

Comment: Olá @Giovanni Ramos Pedrozo. A sua pergunta tem problemas, ela é ampla, e não é um [exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Sem as melhorias necessárias ela não resulta em uma pergunta útil para a comunidade.

Comment: Tenta usar algum serviço de storage tipo s3 da aws. E voce salva a url do s3 no banco.

Answer (score 0):

Crie um bucket no s3, ou outro serviço de bucket. Crie o endpoint para salvar o arquivo nesse bucket. Será retornado um link para acesso ao arquivo (tenha certeza que seja um id unico, GUID ou um outro hash). No seu banco crie uma relacao tipo usuario x link do s3.

Crie outro endpoint para fazer o download deste arquivo (apenas o usuario dono tem acesso)

Material que pode ajudar -> s3 aws, authenticação usando token. Se for usar Django, o proprio tem biblioteca para autenticar.

Answer (score 0):

def gerar_pdf():

```
#Pegando os dados do banco de dados:
cursor = banco.cursor()
comando_SQl = "SELECT * FROM ta_alunos"
cursor.execute(comando_SQl)
dados_lidos = cursor.fetchall()
#Pegando os dados na posição 0
y = 0
#Defindo o nome do arquivo e tamanho da fonte
pdf = canvas.Canvas("tabelas_alunos.pdf")
pdf.setFont("Times-Bold", 15)
pdf.drawString(150, 805, "Monitoramento dos alunos da ETE Bezerros:")
pdf.setFont("Times-Bold", 10)

pdf.drawString(50, 780, "Matrícula")
pdf.drawString(110, 780, "Turma")
pdf.drawString(150, 780, "situação")
pdf.drawString(430, 780, "data_situação")
pdf.drawString(500, 780, "monitoramento")
#Lendo os dados em PDF
for i in range(0, len(dados_lidos)):
    y = y + 20
    pdf.drawString(50, 780 - y, str(dados_lidos[i][1]))
    pdf.drawString(110, 780 - y, str(dados_lidos[i][2]))
    pdf.drawString(150, 780 - y, str(dados_lidos[i][3]))
    pdf.drawString(430, 780 - y, str(dados_lidos[i][4]))
    pdf.drawString(500, 780 - y, str(dados_lidos[i][5]))

    pdf.showPage()
pdf.save()
segunda_tela.label_4.setText("PDF gerado com sucesso!")
```

Comment: Olá meus caros! Bom dia. não estou conseguindo gerar PDF de mais de uma página.  Não pula os dados para outra página. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).